# pandas find re-ordered indices of matching values between columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>import pandas as pd
>>d = {'a':[5,4,3,1,2],'b':[1,2,3,4,5]}
>>df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>df
   a  b
0  5  1
1  4  2
2  3  3
3  1  4
4  2  5
```

Given no repeats of values between a,b, is there a way to compute the variable **indices** such that:

```
df['a'] = df['b'][indices]
```

is satisfied? In this case,

```
>> indices = [4,3,2,0,1]

>> df['b'][indices]
4    5
3    4
2    3
0    1
1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the naive approach would be:

```
def getIndices(a,b):
   rVal = []
   for i in a:
      index = b.index(i)
      rVal.append(index)
   return rVal

a = [5,4,3,1,2]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

result = getIndices(a,b)
print result
# prints [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

I think this will give you `O(nlogn)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
indices = [df['b'][df['b'] == row['a']].index[0]  for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
indices
>> [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.argsort()`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(["c", "b", "a", "x", "e", "d"])
b = np.array(["d", "a", "b", "c", "x", "e"])
idx_a = np.argsort(a)
idx_b = np.argsort(b)
print b[idx_b[idx_a]]
```

the result is:

```
['c' 'b' 'a' 'x' 'e' 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with straight Python (not sure if there's a smarter pandas-specific method).

```
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(list(df['a']))}
indices = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(list(df['b'])), 
                                key=lambda x: d.get(x[1]))]
```

If certain elements of `a` are not in `b` or vice-versa, you'll have to use a smarter key function that's tolerant of missing values (and decide how you want to handle this case, for that matter).